# Ruby on Rails - Edit not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, edit, updates

Trying to update a post that I've made in my Ruby on Rails project but nothing happens. It is really annoying since I don't get any errors and can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

I think it worked before, but since I first wrote the different actions I've added multiple things to my "feed"-model, such as impressions and tags. Don't know if this has affected my update action...

My controller looks like this:

```
  def edit
    @feed = Feed.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
   @feed = Feed.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
     if @feed.update_attributes(params[:feed])
      format.html { redirect_to @feed, notice: 'Feed was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
     else
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
      format.json { render json: @feed.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
    end
  end
```

My feed model looks like this:

```
  attr_accessible :content, :tag_list, :guid, :language, :location, :published_at, :summary, :url, :title, :user_id, :thumbnail_url, :url_to_feed, :type_of_feed
  has_many :impressions, :as=>:impressionable
  validates_length_of :tag_list, :maximum => 10
  acts_as_taggable
```

My view looks like this:

```
  <h1>Editing feed</h1>

  <%= render 'form' %>
  <%= link_to 'Show', @feed %> |
  <%= link_to 'Back', feeds_path %>

  ____________________ form

  <%= form_for(@feed) do |f| %>
   <% if @feed.errors.any? %>
   <div id="error_explanation">
   <h2><%= pluralize(@feed.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this feed from being saved:</h2>
   <ul>
     <% @feed.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
     <% end %>
   </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

 <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :title %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :content %><br />
  <%= f.text_area :content %>
 </div>
  <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :location %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :location %>
  </div>
 <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :language %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :language %>
 </div>

  <div class="field">
<%= f.label :tag_list, "Tags (seperated by spaces)" %><br />
<%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
   <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure that your edit method called? Debug it by viewing log/development.log right after you submit form. You will find controller, action and sended params to it in the given log file.

Comment: Thanks Sergey for the response.

When I look in the development.log I can see my GET request for the edit page being started: Started GET "/feeds/1/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-17 12:27:31 +0100..."      Then I have:
"Started PUT "/feeds/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-17 12:27:36 +0100
Processing by FeedsController#show as HTML"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log entry

```
Started PUT "/feeds/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-17 12:27:36 +0100 Processing by FeedsController#show as HTML
```

says,that the PUT request (sending your form data) is being processed by FeedsController#show, but it has to be processed by FeedsController#update. So your routes seem to be wrong. Check out the [Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

I would use a feeds ressource, because it creates the correct routes automatically:

```
resources :feeds
```

Comment: Thank you!

I did have the resources :feeds in my routes but it needed to be moved to the top!